# How to stop a process when tmux session is detached

Tags: tmux

I often have several tmux sessions running at the same time, in most of these sessions I will have a local server running on a port. What I want is to be able to automatically kill this server when detaching from a tmux session and similarly re-start the server when re-attaching.

Is there anything in tmux that makes this easier, it feels like if there was a hook that tmux provided so that you could run a script before the session was detached or reattached that would do the trick but I can't see anything like this in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward to 2017.
Today tmux has hooks called `client-attached` and `client-detached` that run when clients attaches to the session or detaches from it, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmux a  # attach most recent tmux session
```

or

```
tmux list-sessions  # look for the session you want to kill
tmux a -t 0         # attach session named "0"
```

Once inside the session you want to kill:

```
[Ctrl]-B x          # kill current pane of current session
```

Do that for all the panes and windows within that session and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your `~/.tmux.conf`

`shell-command /bin/bash yourhook.sh`

This would at least give you some functionality when running tmux, but I'm not sure what you would do about a detach hook...